# What is an efficient method for adding thousands of numbers quickly?

Tags: java, modulo, addition, modular-arithmetic

I am attempting to solve a challenge, but I have hit a roadblock. I am a beginner programmer attempting to add tens of thousands of numbers. If I wait long enough, my program can easily yield the correct sum, however, I am looking for a more efficient method.

**What is an efficient method for adding thousands of numbers quickly?**

Side note: I have been reading about modular arithmetic, but I cannot quite wrap my head around it. Not sure if that could be useful for this situation.

I am attempting to get the sum of every prime number below 2 000 000. Here is my code so far:

```
public class Problem10 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        long sum = 0L;

        for(long i = 1L; i < 2000000; i++) {
            if(isPrimeNumber((int)i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int i) {
        int factors = 0;
        int j = 1;

        while (j <= i) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                factors++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        return (factors == 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give an example, and your solution, and we might tell you where you're going wrong. At the moment your question is too broad.

Comment: I suggest looking into concurrency.

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from? Are they random? A series? Read from a file?

Comment: Your question has **nothing** to do with addition and all to do with your use of a slow and inefficient way to calculate prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `isPrimeNumber()` method with this to speed it up substantially.

```
public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int i) {
    if (i==2) return true;
    if (i==3) return true;
    if (i%2==0) return false;
    if (i%3==0) return false;

    int j = 5;
    int k = 2;

    while (j * j <= i) {
        if (i % j == 0) return false;
        j += k ;
        k = 6 - k;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or evaluate the square root of `i` once and avoid a multiplication in each iteration. Could be worth it; only benchmarks can tell.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like homework, so I'm not going to give you the solution in code. The least you can do is code it yourself.

---

In your code, `isPrimeNumber()` is what's taking up most of the time—if I had to guess, I would say 90-99% of it. What you can do to make it faster is implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

To start, you create an array that will hold all the prime numbers<sup>1</sup>. You should start it with a single value: 2. To find more prime numbers, iterate through every integer from 3 to the highest number you want. For each of those numbers, check if that number is divisible by any of the prime numbers in your array. If the next prime number in your array is greater than `i / 2`, you know that `i` is prime, and you can add it to your array.

After you have found all the prime numbers from 1 to n, the only way to sum them is by iterating through the array. That part cannot be optimized, but it will not take very long anyways.

<sup>1</sup> There are two ways to do this. One is to just use an ArrayList or LinkedList, and add numbers as needed. The other is to create an array that is as large or larger than you need. As mentioned [here](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html), the number of primes equal to or less than n is less than `(n / log(n)) * (1 + 1.2762 / log(n))`, as long as n is greater than 598. If n is less than 598, you can just create an array of length 109.

---

In regards to the question in the title, "What is an efficient method for adding thousands of numbers quickly?", the only thing I can think of is multithreading. Create an array of all the numbers you want to sum, then have many threads sum different parts of the array. After that, sum all the results from each thread. This method will probably only be noticeably faster when summing huge amount of numbers, e.g. hundreds of thousands or millions.

Comment: There's also a lazy implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf